# Threading for logging in python

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, optimization

I'm trying to write a logger for a program that is constantly with a high rate of logs per second. I tried to write straight forward logger without treads but because it is constantly accessing the files it could be slow on other devices, so I created a list in my logger class to cache a number of logs. I need a separate thread to write the array on files and empty the array. but while locking the thread it is slowing the whole program, I can't think of any solution. here is my logger class and I need it to be as fast as possible.

```
import threading

class Logger:
 def __init__(self):
        # declaring the class variables
        self._logpath = 'log.csv'
        self.threadlock = threading.Lock()
        self._cached = []

    def write_cache(self):
        time.sleep(__SAVE_DELAY__)
        self.threadlock.acquire()
        self._threadinglock=.acquire()
        for index in range(len(self._cached)):
            cached_log = self._cached[index]
            with open(self._systemlog, 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow([cached_log[1],  # date time
                                     cached_log[2],  # module
                                     cached_log[3],  # method
                                     cached_log[4]])  # massage
        self._cache=[]
        self._threadinglock=.release()

    def system(self, module, method, massage, printlog=False):
        datime = '{:%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
        if printlog:
            print(ColorText(datime + " " + module + "  " + method + " " + str(massage), 'yellow'))
   
        # writing in cache to write on file
        self._threadinglock=.acquire()
        self._cached.append(('system', datime, module, method, massage))
        self._threadinglock=.release()
```

Comment: Um... why do you reopen the file and recreate a new csv.writer for every line of your log file?  The reason for caching is you can write it out all at once.  Why not open the file and create your writer outside the for loop?

Comment: Note that if you want to improve performance in python by using multitasking, processes are preferable over threads since they're not affected by GIL

Comment: @RufusVS thank you I did that and now it is way faster

Comment: @Expolarity thank you for the advice. however, considering it is a logger class from an app, is it reasonable to have a process just for saving the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Logger:
 def __init__(self):
        # declaring the class variables
        self._logpath = 'log.csv'
        self.threadlock = threading.Lock()
        self._cached = []
        self.stop_save = False
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.save_thread, args=(lambda:self.stop_save,))
        self.thread.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop_save = True
        self.thread.join()
        self.write_cache()    

    def save_thread(self, stop):
        while True:
            time.sleep(__SAVE_DELAY__)
            if stop():
                break
            self.threadlock.acquire()
            self.write_cache()
            self.threadlock.release()

    def write_cache(self):
        with open(self._systemlog, 'a+', newline='') as file:
            for index in range(len(self._system_cached)):
                cached_log = self._cached[index]
                
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow([cached_log[0],  # date time
                                     cached_log[1],  # module
                                     cached_log[2],  # method
                                     cached_log[3]])  # massage
        self._cache=[]
        

    def system(self, module, method, massage, printlog=False):
        datime = '{:%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
        if printlog:
            print(ColorText(datime + " " + module + "  " + method + " " + str(massage), 'yellow'))
   
        # writing in cache to write on file
        self._threadinglock=.acquire()
        self._cached.append(('system', datime, module, method, massage))
        self._threadinglock=.release()



log = Logger()
for i in range(10**5):
    log.system("test", "Test", "Logging really fast")
```